# How to create a selector using id and suffix?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I got this element:

```
<button id="uniqName_1_0-submit" class="dijitInline flatBtn transparentCtBtn largeCtBtn dijitButton" type="button" dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onClick" dojoattachpoint="focusNode,titleNode" tabindex="1" title="Share my health summary" widgetid="uniqName_1_0-submit" style="user-select: none;">
    <span class="iconRel">
        <span class="dijitInline iconNode dijitNoIcon" dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></span>
        <span class="dijitButtonText" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">Don't Share</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

I need to set different `font-size` for a case of button and id suffix with '-submit'.

I tried this and it didn't work for me:

```
button[id$="-submit"] {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Seems to work - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOOvWZQ - Please demo.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works. Is it possible that there are other style rules on the child elements of your <button> that are interfering with the font-size you're setting here? If so, please post the css.

Comment: @Paulie_D it's not working in my local, although it seems to be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I followed the hint of checking who is interfering me.

So I used `important` to solve my issue.

```
.wcag button[id$="-submit"] {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```